# How Fetch file From GitLab using by GitLab4j

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-api

How to fetch file from gitLab, using by GitLab4j
my code look:

`

```
    Object obj = 19851511;
    GitLabApi gitLabApi = new GitLabApi("https://gitlab.com/", "TOKEN");

    RepositoryFile file = gitLabApi.getRepositoryFileApi().getFile(obj
            , "https://gitlab.com/kashirin.kostiantyn/fackinproj/-/blob/5cfd2c42ece5532aa174ec8b90700a656651ff92/test.rtf"
            , "master");
```

`
Link in browser is work!
After, I have error: Exception in thread "main" org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApiException: 404 File Not Found

or: Exception in thread "main" org.gitlab4j.api.GitLabApiException: 404 Commit Not Found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you interest answer in my question, so is

`

```
Object obj = 19851511;

GitLabApi gitLabApi = new GitLabApi("https://gitlab.com/", "TOKEN");
RepositoryFile file = gitLabApi.getRepositoryFileApi().getFile(obj,"src/.gitkeep" , "master");

    System.out.println("TExt decodet \n"+file.getDecodedContentAsString());
    System.out.println("This all info from FILE \n"+file);
```

`
enjoy

Thank me!)

and one more thing!
If you get "SSLHandhakeExeption", so use

`gitLabApi.setIgnoreCertificateErrors(true);`

First declare gitlabApi,
after
gitLabApi.setIgnoreCertificateErrors(true);
,and after all,  RepositoryFile